# Adding multiple dropdown menu's next to each other using JS, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get multiple dropdown menu's next to each other, however I am running into a problem. I have the two categories I want to have as dropdown in the header, however only 1 of them seems to work. With the non-working dropdown menu nothing happens when I click on it.

```js
let click = document.querySelector('.click');
let list = document.querySelector('.list');

click.addEventListener("click", () => {
  list.classList.toggle('newlist');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F6D604;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  height: 80%;
  background: transparent;
}

img {
  image-rendering: auto;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.inner_header {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  display: block;
  border-color: black;
}

.click {
  background-color: #F6D604;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-color: black;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.click:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}

.links {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.newlist {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.links {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: black;
}

.links:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
    <a href="../project/index.html">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <img src="assets/images/LOGO.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="click">About</button>
      <div class="list">
        <button class="links">About us</button>
        <button class="links">Contact us</button>
      </div>
      <button class="click">Language</button>
      <div class="list">
        <button class="links">EN</button>
        <button class="links">NL</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` will pick up the first matching element, whereas `querySelectorAll` will get a collection of all matching elements. You need to iterate through the elements to apply the listener. This solution clears out any open nav menus when the other is clicked. Also, it makes use of the `[...]` spread operator to iterate through elements. I added a new class `navitem` so that each submenu would show where it should.

```js
let click = document.querySelectorAll('.click');
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
const showSub = (e) => {
    [...list].forEach(el => el.classList.remove('newlist')); // reset
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.list').classList.toggle('newlist');
    // this also works
    //e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('newlist');
  }
  [...click].forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", showSub));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F6D604;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  height: 80%;
  background: transparent;
}

img {
  image-rendering: auto;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.inner_header {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  display: block;
  border-color: black;
}

.click {
  background-color: #F6D604;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-color: black;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.navitem {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.click:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}

.links {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.newlist {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.links {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: black;
}

.links:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
    <a href="../project/index.html">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <img src="assets/images/LOGO.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class='navitem'>
        <button class="click">About</button>
        <div class="list">
          <button class="links">About us</button>
          <button class="links">Contact us</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='navitem'>
        <button class="click">Language</button>
        <div class="list">
          <button class="links">EN</button>
          <button class="links">NL</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `forEach` to address every button-list pair.

I believe the below code solves your JavaScript issues. Adjust the CSS as needed (I have changed the original HTML a little).

```js
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.drop');

drops.forEach(function(drop) {
  let click = drop.querySelector('.click');
  let list = drop.querySelector('.list');
  click.addEventListener("click", () => {
    list.classList.toggle('newlist');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F6D604;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  height: 80%;
  background: transparent;
}

img {
  image-rendering: auto;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.inner_header {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  display: block;
  border-color: black;
}

.drop {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.click {
  background-color: #F6D604;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-color: black;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.click:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}

.links {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.newlist {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.links {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border-color: black;
}

.links:hover {
  background-color: #F6D604;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
    <a href="../project/index.html">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <img src="assets/images/LOGO.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="drop">
        <button class="click">Language</button>
        <div class="list">
          <button class="links">EN</button>
          <button class="links">NL</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="drop">
        <button class="click">About</button>
        <div class="list">
          <button class="links">About us</button>
          <button class="links">Contact us</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way `querySelector` works, is it returns the *first* matching DOM element. In your case, because you use the `click` class for both buttons, the listener is only attached to the first one. Check out [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (at the return value header).

In this case I would suggest either using two classes and adding listeners to both separately, or accessing both buttons using someting like:

```js
let clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click');

for (let click of clicks) {
  click.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    list.classList.toggle('newlist');
  });
}
```

Comment: While you're right about querySelector, you should probably show what `list` refers to (since there are multiple occurrences)